# Use Aspectj to find List of classes implementing a certain interface

Tags: java, aspectj

Is it possible using AspectJ to find a list of all Classes which implement a certain interface. For e.g I have an interface `MatchRule`. Then I can have classes `DefaultMatchRule` and `CustomMatchRule` concrete clases which implement `MatchRule` interface.
Now at runtime I want to get a list which will have 2 classes `DefaultMatchRule` and `CustomMatchRule`

```
public interface MatchRule {

}

public class DefaultMatchRule implements MatchRule {

}

public class CustomMatchRule implements MatchRule {

}

public aspect FindSubClasses {

// some thing to find list of classes implementing MatchRule interface

}
```

Comment: Could you please explain the reasons why you need such a list? I cannot imagine such a reason except of analyzing the code. In all other cases you could crosscut the classes at the moments when you use them.

Answer (score 1):

AspectJ is not designed to finding classes. Your best option is to scan the classpath and use reflection.

If you can live with compile-time information, the Eclipse AJDT plugin offers good graphical information for all AspectJ advises.

But if you can live with some limitations, you can find the classes for all objects that is advised by AspectJ.

A solution that prints out the class names for all objects of classes that implements MatchRule:

```
@Aspect
public class FindSubClassesAspect {

    @Pointcut("execution(demo.MatchRule+.new(..))")
    public void demoPointcut() {
    }

    @After("demoPointcut()")
    public void afterDemoPointcut(
            JoinPoint joinPoint) {
        FindSubClasses.addMatchRuleImplememtation(
                joinPoint.getTarget().getClass().getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

A class that contain the information about all the MatchRule implementations:

```
public enum FindSubClasses {    
    ;

    private static Set<String> matchRuleImplementations = 
        new HashSet<String>();

    public static void addMatchRuleImplememtation(String className) {
        matchRuleImplementations.add(className);
    }

    public static Collection<String> getMatchRuleImplementations() {        
        return matchRuleImplementations;
    }
}
```

A simple driver that demonstrate that the aspect works:

```
public class Driver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new DefaultMatchRule();
        new CustomMatchRule();

        Collection<String> matchRuleImplementations = 
            FindSubClasses.getMatchRuleImplementations();

        System.out.print("Clases that implements MatchRule: ");
        for (String className : matchRuleImplementations) {
            System.out.print(className + ", ");
        }
    }
}
```

The output of executing this driver:

> Clases that implements MatchRule: DefaultMatchRule, CustomMatchRule,

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The only possible way to do this at runtime is probably scanning all your packages and checking to see whether your classes implement that interface.

I can't think of any other way this is possible. In fact, Eclipse has a context menu option that shows the "Implementors" of an interface but they achieve that by scanning the packages.

Comment: Thanks for your answer; I thought since I can define a pointcut in aspectj like * MatchRule+ ; there would be something like a pointcut context where I can get this information. I also had a look at PointCutParser but could not find any information in it.